# Context doesnt map entities to parent

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I´m trying to display some data from a Database using `EF-Core`. The provided data is already inserted into the database using `EF-core` and works as intended.
I want to output a JSON of Person with associated `telephones and emails` using `EF-core` but only get a JSON without the `telephones and emails`.

Here are my Entities:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public enum Geschlecht
        {
            U = 0,
            W = 1,
            M = 2
        }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string TitelVor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Vorname { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string TitelNach { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Zusatz { get; set; }
        public DateTime Geburtsdatum { get; set; }
        public string Notiz { get; set; }
        public List<EMail> EMails { get; set; } = new List<EMail>();
        public List<Telefon> Telefone { get; set; } = new List<Telefon>();
    }
    public class Telefon
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("AdresstypId")]
        public Adresstyp Adresstyp { get; set; }
        public int AdresstypId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TelefontypId")]
        public Telefontyp Telefontyp { get; set; }
        public int TelefontypId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Vorwahl { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Nummer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Durchwahl { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Primär { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
    }
    public class EMail
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("AdresstypId")]
        public Adresstyp Adresstyp { get; set; }
        public int AdresstypId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Primär { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Context:

```
    public class AdressverwaltungContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Personen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Adresse> Adressen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EMail> EMails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Adresstyp> Adresstypen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Telefon> Telefon { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Telefontyp> Telefontyp { get; set; }

        public AdressverwaltungContext(DbContextOptions<AdressverwaltungContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.Migrate();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                        .HasMany(x => x.Telefone)
                        .WithOne(y => y.Person);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                        .HasMany(x => x.EMails)
                        .WithOne(y => y.Person);

        }
    }
```

And here my Controller:

```
public class DummyController : Controller
{
    private AdressverwaltungContext adressverwaltungContext;

    public DummyController(AdressverwaltungContext ctx)
    {
        adressverwaltungContext = ctx;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/GetAllPersons")]
    public JsonResult GetAllPersons()
    {
        return Json(adressverwaltungContext.Personen);
    }
}
```

I am using `Postman` to display the Results of my API and get the following Result when calling the Method "GetAllPersons":

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "titelVor": "test",
        "name": "name",
        "vorname": "vorname",
        "titelNach": "titelnach",
        "zusatz": "zusatz",
        "geburtsdatum": "1990-01-01T00:00:00",
        "notiz": "test",
        "eMails": [],
        "telefone": []
    }
]
```

As you can see `telefone and emails` are empty.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What your method Json does?

Comment: That is a built-in Method from Microsoft.AspNetcore.Mvc: Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult object that serializes the specified data object to JSON.

Comment: so, you should looking if there are settings of Json method. The problems seems to be with List<T>

Comment: The Json Method is not the problem here, breakpointing the return and checking the adressverwaltungContext.Personen object before the output, shows that telefone and emails is empty before the object is passed to the Json method.

Comment: It was not clear from your description. So the json part is useless to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Include()` in your queries to let EF know you are interested in it bringing the related entities as well. So something like:

```
adressverwaltungContext.Persons.Include('Email').Include('Telefon')
```

You might need to call `AsQueryable()` first on Personen `DbSet` to get the `Include` extension method.

The reason EF is not retrieving Email and Telefon by default is that it thinks these are not "owned" by Person but rather are standalone entities that have relations with Person and you might not always be interested in retrieving all these related entities.

Instead you could let EF know that these are logically part of Person and should be handled with it as one unit. You can achieve that by removing the Person navigation properties from Email and Telefon and using `OwnsMany()` in model builder.

Comment: I could not get the ASQueryable/Include to work, but OwnsMany worked great, which seems is the better solution for my case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes `OwnsMany` aligns better with your model because it's really an ownership relationship. Glad it worked you're welcome